# How do I ensure that a referencing table also has data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My Postgres database has the following schema where the the user can store multi profile images.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT GENERATE AS ALWAYS PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE images(
    id INT GENERATE AS ALWAYS PRIMARY KEY,
    url VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE user_images(
    user_id INT REFERENCES users(id),
    image_id INT REFERENCES images(id)
);
```

How do I ensure that when I insert a user object, I also insert at least one user image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do so very easily . . . and I wouldn't encourage you to enforce this.  Why?  The problem is a "chick and egg" problem.  You cannot insert a row into `users` because there is no image.  You cannot insert a row into `user_images` because there is no `user_id`.

Although you can handle this situation with transactions or delayed constraint checking, that covers only half the issue -- because you have to prevent deletion of the last image.

Here are two alternative.

First, you can simply add a `main_image_id` to the `users` table and insist that it be `NOT NULL`.  Voila!  At least one image is required.

Second, you can use a trigger to maintain a count of images in `users`.  Then treat rows with no images as "deleted" so they are never seen.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert a data into a table database can return a id from row which was inserted. So, if id > 0 the row has been inserted. But first, add column id (bigserial, auto increment, unique) to all tables.

```
INSERT INTO user_images VALUES (...) RETURNING id;
```